# Unquoted expression injection bash

Tags: linux, bash, security

I recently read that it is dangerous to use unquoted parameter in bash scripts. my question is:

Is it possible to bypass the condition in order to make it always true?

```
if test $TOTO -eq ${1} 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "Bypass"
else
    echo "No"
fi
```

Regards,

R

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're asking whether you can choose a parameter `$1` so that this condition is true for any integer value of `$TOTO`, then yes:

```
./yourscript "0 -o foo"
```

This makes any condition become

```
test 1234 -eq 0 -o foo
```

This is the equivalent of `1234 == 0 || "foo"` in other languages, with one irrelevant comparison OR'd with the truth value of the string `foo`.

Since `test` considers all non-empty strings to be true, this expression is always true.

Comment: Good answer, but you should explain why this works.

Answer (score 0):

As @that other guy said, the "0 -o whatever" will bypass the check. The reason why it does is because of the -o option of the test binary:

```
EXPRESSION1 -o EXPRESSION2
              either EXPRESSION1 or EXPRESSION2 is true
```

So basically what the script will do is test if

```
$TOTO -eq 0 || "whatever"
```

Since non empty string are always True the overall check result will be True and here is the bypass :)